# Multiprocessing Questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

instead of it printing numbers more than once. i know it works in with threading but i want to try using multiprocessing instead because it uses less cpu

```python
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
def number():
    while len(list) > 0:
        print(list[0])
        list.pop(0)
def start():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        threads = []
        for i in range(int(input('Threads: '))):
            threads.append(Process(target=number))
        for thread in threads:
            try:
                thread.start()
                sleep(0.3)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        for thread in threads:
            try:
                thread.join()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input()
```

I am trying to do multiprocessing and i want the output to be like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Are you on Windows (where new python's are spawned) or linux/mac (where new processes for forked)?

Comment: As an aside, don't name your variable "list" as it masks the builtin `list` which creates lists.

Comment: Multiprocessing does not reduce CPU usage. MP increases it. The goal of MP is to _maximize_ CPU usage to _minimize_ execution time. In your code, you added `sleep` so I don't think you gaining anything with MP.

Comment: You call `start()` at module level and then you have an extra `input()` under the `if __name__ ...` protector. I think that should just be `start` under the if. But it also answers the platform question - on Windows `start()` would be called again on each subprocess, creating an infinite number of them.

Comment: Note that the number function is not thread safe. The item printed may not be the item popped because another thread may well have executed and popped the value in that time. I suspect that's why you have `sleep(.3)` in there. But really all that means is that the first one or two threads will do all the work and the theads at the end will find the list is already empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you ran this code with threads, each thread had access to the same `list`. When one thread popped a value, that value was popped for all of them. With `multiprocessing`, each execution thread gets a unique view of the list. The actions performed by one process are not seen by the others. In windows this is done by regenerating the list in the subprocess. In linux/mac this is done by the operating system. Each process gets a copy-on-write view of the list which gives them unique physical memory to hold any changes.

Since you want each item of the list to be processed only once, you need a way to hand the values to the subprocesses. `multiprocessing.pool` does this, so lets give it a try.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

mylist = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

def number(num):
    return num

def start():
    with Pool(min(len(mylist), cpu_count())) as pool:
        for num in pool.map(number, mylist):
            print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

And there it is. `Pool` handled the process list and the job of handing out the work items one at a time.